# virtualenv : installed packages are not avaliable outisde the environment

Tags: python

I have 2 versions of python 2.7 and 3.3. I installed virtualenv hoping that I can work using two different python version.

I created my first project environment:

```
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python2.7 first
```

and installed pymysql package which is available to that environment only.

Now I want the same package to be available globally - how can I do that?

When I run pip install without setting the environment it actually installs in 3.3 version site packages which eventually fails as it is compatible for 2.7?

Comment: Without activating your environment you can go `pip install <package>` this will install it in your global environment.

Comment: But I have 2 versions of python 2.7 and 3.3 and I want it to be installed for 2.7 - how can I do that?

Comment: @Prakash use `pip-2.7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have packages available globally you must install them globally. `virtualenv` is made specifically for making separate package installations. It doesn't provide anything else so I have no idea why are you using it.

Comment: Absolutely, isolating environments is the **whole point** of virtualenv.

Comment: I have 2 versions of python 2.7 and 3.3 and I want it to be installed for 2.7 - how can I do that? When I run pip install it actually installs in 3.3 version site packages which eventually fails as it is compatible for 2.7

Comment: @Prakash is that's your actual question, you should edit your original post to make that clear.

Comment: Thanks I changed my question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use virtualenv to have two Python version installed. In fact, virtualenv doesn't help with that at all. Virtualenv is to install several installs of the *same* Python version.

So to have two different versions of Python installed you simply just install two different versions of Python. It's that simple.

http://regebro.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/newbie-hint-on-installing-python-and-its-modules-and-packages/